# How do I change state within a child component by calling function in its parent?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am attempting to change the state within a child component every time I call a function in it's parent component. How would I go about doing this? For Example,

```
class ParentComponent extends Component {
function onClick(){
  // some function here to change child components state
}
render(){
  return (
         <div>
         <ChildComponent />
         <button onClick={this.onClick.bind(this)}>
         </div>
        )
  }

class ChildComponent extends Component {
constructor(props){
  super(props)
  this.state = {
     MyState: 1
  }
}
render(){
  return(
    <div>
      {this.state.MyState}
    </div>
  )
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to my understanding you are trying to achieve this:

```
class ParentComponent extends Component {
constructor(props){
  super(props)
  this.state = {
     MyState: 1
  }
}

function onClick(){
  this.setState({MyState:this.state.MyState + 1})
}
render(){
  return (
         <div>
         <ChildComponent sendToChild={this.state.MyState}/>
         <button onClick={this.onClick.bind(this)}>
         </div>
        )
  }

class ChildComponent extends Component {

render(){
  return(
    <div>
      {this.props.MyState}
    </div>
  )
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Call setState in your `onClick` handler -- this causes a rerender in the ParentComponent as well as any child component (unless a component returns false in `shouldComponentUpdate`, but you don't have this function implemented). However  your child component will visually not change even when rerendered currently since it has no props.

Not sure what you want to achieve exactly, but if you were to move the state `MyState`from ChildComponent to ParentComponent and pass `MyState` as a prop to ChildComponent, and in the `onClick` handler call `setState` and increment `MyState` then the ChildComponent would visually update.

Answer (score 0):

Either put your `onClick` handler in the child component,  [lift the state up](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/lifting-state-up.html) or pass the `onClick` through props.

What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: The problem is, I'd like to execute the `onClick` handler inside the parent component, and therefore putting the onClick handler in my child component wouldn't be ideal. Passing the `onClick` through props would not be ideal, as I am trying to have the function that is called change the state of the child component, not the parents.